# User session timeout expiry not throwing confirmDialog for long timeouts

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, session-timeout

I have a problem with the implementation of the user session timeout expiry. In our project, we are using JSF for the web design framework and primefaces as the Facelet component. I have developed the following code in my development:

```
    <p:idleMonitor onidle="idleDialog.show();" rendered="#{loginBean.loggedIn}" timeout="#{loginBean.activeUser.userTimeOut}" />
        <p:confirmDialog header="#{lang.signOut}" message="#{lang.signOutMess}" widgetVar="idleDialog" modal="true" closable="false" appendToBody="true" >
            <p:button outcome="logout.xhtml" value="#{lang.signOut}"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>
```

The code above perfectly works with the users with the short timeouts such as 1-20 minutes. It is automatically throwing the confirm dialog with the signOutMess. However, the same code is not working with the users with higher timeouts such as one hour. It is not throwing the confirm dialog but signing out the user from the system. Actually, for example if the user with the timeout - one hour time goes into one screen in the system and stayed idle on that frame for one hour, the screen is not changed but when the user tries to open another frame on the system, it is directly directing to the logout.xhtml which is actually the target and make the user to be signed out from the system but again I'd like to state, it is not throwing the confirmDialog.

What would you friends recommend me to do for that case?

Yours sincerely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you misunderstand what the idleTimeout component is actually doing.  It is essentially a client side timer that can perform a server side postback or a client side event after a specified interval of inactivity.  Technically speaking this can be used to help keep a users session alive.

The problem is that if there is no server side activity for a specified period of time then the users session on the server will timeout per the web application or server settings.  If the session times out on the server then the idleMonitor isn't suddenly going to start working.

You can increase the session timeout setting on your web server if 20 minutes is unacceptable.

Comment: Your opinions look like true. I am gonna investigate it and return with a reply. Thank you...

Comment: Dear maple_shaft, you were right. Thank you for your endorsements.